# C program to print line number in which given string exists in a text file

Tags: c, string

I have written a C program that opens a text file and compares the given string with the string present in the file. I'm trying to print the line number in which the same string occurs, but I am unable to get the proper output: output does not print the correct line number.

I would appreciate any help anyone can offer, Thank you!

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int num = 0, line_number = 1;
    char string[50];
    char student[100] = { 0 }, chr;

    while (student[0] != '0') {
        FILE *in_file = fopen("student.txt", "r");
        if (in_file == NULL) {
            printf("Error file missing\n");
            exit(1);
        }

        printf("please enter a word \n");
        scanf("%s", student);
        while (fscanf(in_file, "%s", string) == 1) {
            if (chr == '\n') {
                if (strstr(string, student) == 0) {
                    break;
                } else
                    line_number += 1;
            }
        }
        printf("line number is: %d\n", line_number);

        fclose(in_file);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `fscanf` will discard the newline. Try using `fgets()` to read one line at time and then `strstr` on that.

Comment: @JohnnyMopp Yessir, i will try that. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot read lines with `while (fscanf(in_file, "%s", string)`, the newlines will be consumed by `fscanf()` preventing you from counting them.

Here is an alternative using `fgets()`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
    char string[200];
    char student[100];
    int num = 0, line_number = 1;

    FILE *in_file = fopen("student.txt", "r");
    if (in_file == NULL) {
        printf("Error file missing\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    printf("please enter a word \n");
    if (scanf("%s", student) != 1) {
        printf("No input\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    while (fgets(string, sizeof string, in_file)) {
        if (strstr(string, student)) {
            printf("line number is: %d\n", line_number);
        }
        if (strchr(string, '\n')) {
            line_number += 1;
        }
        fclose(in_file);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I really do appreciate the answer.

Comment: The output still does not seem to be printing the line in which the inputted string occurs, I have not been able to figure out why

Comment: @cat020: the line `printf("line number is: %d\n", line_number);` only prints the lie number. Change it to `printf("student.txt:%d:%s", line_number, string);` to get the line contents as well, like `grep`.